# Trace of ui-notification after being killed

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

How to remove the trace of ui-notification 
These notifications making user to unable to click on buttons 
Even notification killed when user geeting to point again its popping ,blocking the user to press button.

[[image: Notification is already killed [1]]

**My controller code**

```
 $scope.loginForm = function(isValid) {
    // $window.location.href = '/home';
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if (isValid) {
        service.login({
            data: {
                user: $scope.login
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            authService.isLoggedIn = response.status == "success";
            if (response.status == "success") {
                authService.set("userInfo", response.data)
                authService.role = response.data.role;
                authService.name = response.data.name;
                Notification.success({message:'Successfully logged in'});
                // Notification.clearAll("Successfully logged in");
            }
            else{
                Notification.success('Invalid Credentials');
            }
            // console.log(response.data.redirect)
            $location.path(response.data.redirect); 
        });
    } else {
        Notification.error('Error Login');
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi, where is your angularJs code! where is your codes!! where is your sample for help people to answer you!... improve your question please.

Comment: I used notification.success alone . i attached my angular code

Comment: That "Notification Service", just have a "success" function ? go to this service and check if it include "close" or "clear" (something like that) function.

Comment: https://github.com/alexcrack/angular-ui-notification nop having some more options . Clearall function is available but its not working

Comment: Did you use the "Notification" configs? example "delay: 10000" and etc options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**option 1: App Config**

```
app.config(["NotificationProvider", function (notificationProvider) {
    notificationProvider.setOptions({
            delay: 1000,
            startTop: 20,
            startRight: 10,
            verticalSpacing: 20,
            horizontalSpacing: 20,
            positionX: 'left',
            positionY: 'bottom'
        });
    }]);
```

> you can use **delay option** on app config to hide message faster, if not, go **option 2**.

**option 2: make external service**

```
    app.service("closeNotify", function ($timeout) {
        this.closeNotification = function (time) {
            $timeout(function() {
                $(".message").click();
            }, time);
        }
    });
```

> In this service we use **"jQuery"** to handle **click()** function, after popup the message we set our service to hide message after specific time, **go to how use it**

**how**

```
    app.controller("ctrl", ["$scope", "Notification", "closeNotify", 
    function (scope, notification, closeNotify) {

        notification.primary('Primary notification');
        closeNotify(1000);
    }]);
```